# Subsetting a matrix returns a vector not a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset

Using the below code, I am trying to subset the id matrix which has a dim of 100,000*27. The code below keeps rows that have values of 1,3 and 5. The subsetting is successful but what I got (id13) is a vector, not a matrix. How can I modify the code below to retain a subsetted matrix?

```
id13 <- id[id[,] %in% c(1, 3, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter <- matrix(id %in% c(1, 3, 5), nrow(id))
```

Assuming you want to subset rows and columns:

```
id13 <- id[rowSums(filter) > 0, colSums(filter) > 0]
```

If you only want to subset rows (as in your question):

```
id13 <- id[rowSums(filter) > 0,]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
id[apply(id, 2, \(row) any(c(1, 3, 5) %in% row)), ]
```

Replace `any` with `all` as appropriate.

Comment: Your suggested code does not return any error but it does not subset the matrix as I want.

Comment: Interestingly, I got the same answer from Chargpt!

Comment: If does subset *rows* as you asked in your question, but `apply` should be avoided for performance reasons.

Comment: @jeanlain, thanks for pointing that out; your solution `microbenchmarks` more than twice at fast.